# oppose, be opposed to

Tags: verbs

> 1. I am totally opposed to abortion.
> 2. I totally oppose myself to abortion. (I made the 2 sentence)

I know that the 2 is awkward.
Anyway, could two sentences have the same meaning?

I think that the 2 sentence is quite understandable, though it is not an usual expression.

Comment: In this context, we don't use the reflexive "oppose myself to {something}", though we can say "I am going to set myself against {something}".  It is either "I oppose {something}" or "I am opposed to {something}".

Comment: #2 should just be "I totally oppose abortion". No need for the reflexive pronoun or the preposition *to*. With that change, the two sentences are essentially equivalent in meaning.

Comment: @ThePhoton Then, what if the 2 sentence is modified as I totally oppose my opinion to abortion.

Comment: And I find a sentence consisting of 'Subject oppose Object to Object' structure from Wiktionary.
*[T]hree walls had been left standing, with large intervals between each; and they would certainly oppose a most formidable interruption to an invader. (in the sentence, oppose means To present or set up in opposition)

Comment: I think that 'I am opposed to' form is from the reflexive sentence. 
Because referring to WordReference Dictionary, oppose is defined as 'to set (something) over against something else in place'

Comment: @EvaristeGalois, why would you oppose your own opinion? It's grammatical, but logically nonsense. Where did you find your Wiktionary example? It isn't in the Wiktionary page for *oppose*. When I search for it I find it is taken from a book from 1839. If it wasn't a mis-print, then this usage of *oppose* has become archaic. Nowadays we'd use *impose* instead of *oppose* in that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is "to be opposed to (something)".

> **I am** completely **opposed to** the entire concept of *decaf* coffee.

I think what you're trying to do is use the reflexive pronoun as *emphasis* that you, yourself, are opposed to something.  In this case the reflexive pronoun comes before the verb:

> I, **myself, am** completely **opposed** to waking before ten in the morning, and am proud to say I've never seen a sunrise.

As Tᴚoɯɐuo points out, we don't normally reflexively *oppose ourselves* -- if you do that then the reflexive pronoun becomes *object* of the verb "to oppose".

> I want to quit drinking, but I keep **opposing myself** at every turn, by getting into stressful situations where can't help but find an open bar to unwind.

Still, "oppose" is an odd word to use here.  More common would be something like "fight myself".

Comment: No, I put 'myself' as the direct object of oppose in the 2. I didn't write it for emphasis.

Comment: And I think that 'I am opposed to' form originated from 'I oppose myself to'.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois  ok ...  then sentence 2 is incorrect, and in any case has the opposite meaning from sentence 1.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois  also it doesn't really make sense with something like a philosophy.  You can be "of two minds about something" though.